# Difference between FileStreamResult and FilePathResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I have a simple controller which returns images:

```
public class ImageController : Controller
{
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "StationeryImageCache")]
    public FileResult Show(int customerId, string imageName)
    {
        try
        {
            var path = string.Concat(Config.ImageDir, customerId, @"\", imageName);
            return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), "image/jpeg");
        }
        catch(System.IO.FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            throw new MissingImageException(imageName);
        }
    }
}
```

My manager noticed the FileStreamResult during a code review and mentioned I should swap it with:

```
return new FilePathResult(path, "image/jpeg");
```

This made sense to me so I did it.  But after a few days one of our other devs reported that some of the images I was returning were coming back corrupted.  Specifically, there were a lot of images that were cut off at some point.  The size of the image was correct, but bottom 25% - 40% of the image was simply gone.

When looking at the original image on the file system there was nothing wrong with it.  I plopped the image in a browser and it looked fine.  But my controller was only returning part of the image. Worse, it was only some images that were issues... approximately %30 of them... though I'm unable to find any particular differences between those that work and those that don't.

While trying to debug this I reverted the action's result back to the FileStreamResult, and suddenly everything was working again.

Does anyone know an explanation for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears that the HttpResponse.TransmitFile that is used in FilePathResult has or have had a few problems. It might depend on the version of Windows you are running your server according to this [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/902780). If you search on Google for something like 'response.TransmitFile error' you get a lot of errors.

I guess you should use your original code!

Comment: Nice find! I was about to start digging into the source but I wouldn't have noticed this even if I had.